# Yii2 как установить максимальную дату у датапикера

Tags: php, yii2, bootstrap

Я использую в форме `DatePicker widget`, мне необходимо установить максимальную дату , что бы больше нее пользователь не мог выбрать дату, пишу в плагине
`'pluginOptions' => ['maxDate'=>'-10y']` , но это ни к чему не приводит
можно выбрать и 20 год рождения. Может кто то сталкивался или может по другому указывать нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам разобрался, 
параметры этого датапикера описаны здесь:
http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate
что бы установить минимальную и максимальную дату есть две опции
startDate и endDate в них указываются даты, соотетвственно начальная и конечная. Эти опции нало размещать в 'pluginOptions', может кому-то понадобится.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы указываете параметры в pluginOptions, то подозреваю, что вы используете виджет календаря от **kartik-v**. У меня атрибуты **minDate** и **maxDate** не сработали в данном виджете. В yii2 также есть стандартный виджет календаря **yii\jui\DatePicker**

**minDate** и **maxDate** — это опция у плагина jquery. Если вы возьмете **yii\jui\DatePicker**, то эти параметры следует указывать в массиве **$clientOptions = []**
Например:

```
'clientOptions' => [
     'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
     'todayHighlight' => true,
     'minDate' => '-3d',
     'maxDate' => '+2d',
]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но jquery не пойдет нужно именно kartik-v

Comment: @SergeyP kartik-v сам использует компонент jquery ui

Comment: да, jquery тупанул